# html css design good practice?

Tags: html, css

I am an novice web developer. I usually use multiple hierarchical tables to get the design I want. I have been looking over a lot of web 2.0 websites and most of them seem to use the div / float combination.

Which is a better practice to use? Also since I'm well versed with the table approach, what advantages does the div/float approach give?

Comment: tables can still be used, mostly for when you are actually creating a excel like form and such, but for the page layout css is the way to go, you will have a lot more flexibility with css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the HTML standard says, tables should only be used for their designed aim: beeing tables. Instead of using tables for layouting, css provides huge functionality to position and layout html entites. The huge advantage is (or should be) that the single exchange of a stylesheet result in a comnplete other design (most table layouts must be restructured from scratch to provide a new design). Thus the use of css should result in more flexibility.

One realy good start into this task should be the zengarden, displaying very much css designs based on one html page.

http://www.csszengarden.com/

Comment: i see your point everytime im unhappy with the design i need to start from scratch...! Ill look into this thank you...

Comment: And of course, as with nearly all "look how great things can be with CSS" sites, all but one of the designs on the first two pages of design are fixed-width ones that look ridiculous on a wide browser window. It would be **really great** if CSS were up to the task of eliminating tables from layout, but it still isn't. :-( (The rapidly-approaching death of IE6 will help, though.) Agree with your central point about flexibility, though. If you can work with CSS's limitations and browser issues. I usually try to do that, and only resort to tables when it's just going to be a mess with pure CSS.

Comment: I totally agree to you, @T.J. Crowder, unfortunately the use of css doesnt result in a swiss army knife, beeing able to rule all customer design request and so on. Nevertheless and in my humble opinion, the use of css results in thinner code, hence provides a bit more overview and flexiblity in comparsion to table layouts.

Comment: Absolutely, yes. You have to look to CSS first, and only resort to other techniques when necessary.

Answer (score 3):

This is a great debate and requires a couple of points that seem to get lost in the wishwash of the internet.

1. Tables are not a bad thing
2. Tables have a real purpose

Before when the internet was new and browsers chugged through html like a drunk chick at a kegger people thought it was a good idea to use tables for design... I mean why not it places your elements in a table.

Well then CSS came along with a cup of coffee and a cold shower and told those browsers to slow down.  CSS denotes all the style of a page.  This allows your DOM to be separate for styling and your layout to be dynamic.  I don't really need to go into all the reasons CSS is a good thing but as for tables it was really important.

If you like a browser treat HTML as a mark up then the markup should actually denote it's content.  Having a bunch of images in a table isn't a table at all its just a lazy way to show a buch of images.

With CSS you can now use a table for good things like DataSheets,  User Lists, and anything else you would see yourself putting into and Excel Spread sheet.  This way all the styling can be done in your stylesheet.

It's not that that tables are bad, now they can be used for what they intended for... tables.

CSS also offers the `display: table` there is a lot of debate around it but I personally think this is the way to go if you want to style like a table and don't feel like floats. It allows for you to Style like a table in your Style Sheet so you are not actually using a table element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good article about this issue

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/08/from-table-hell-to-div-hell/

btw, this issue has been discussed so many times in so many topics :-<

Answer (score 0):

Divs have the advantage of being more flexible. You have greater control and they are easier to update or modify.

When you create the whole layout with tables, and let's you need to use 2 columns, if you later decide to add a third column, you wi have to make very radical changes to make it happen.

Css on the other hand is powerful enough to be 1: a complete language to define the layout of your page. 2: it doesn't clutter your html, you can have 1 person design the html and another to do the css.

check out [css tricks](http://css-tricks.com/) and you will never use tables again... unless for a table.

ps: You can create 2 completely different layout from 1 html and 2 different css.

Answer (score 0):

Using div you can change all the design only changing your css.

You can give to the browser the most important content first. It doesn't matter where you are going to show it in the browser, so the robots (google) can see what is most important in your content.

Tables are thought to represent tabular data, not to format pages.

The css can make your web accesible to blind people navigators.